# Dumping Stack trace from an if statement in for loop in C

Tags: c

The i variable is causing my program to crash and it'll work without it but I'm not understanding why and if I replace with any other number it'll work but not do what I'd like.

```
    void longest_prime_factor(int n){

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

            if (n % i == 0) printf("true\n");
        }

   }
    longest_prime_factor(17);
```

Output

```
0 [main] primefactors 238 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to primefactors.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: Trying to mod by 0 won't work, when i = 0. (Division by 0)

Answer (score 2):

The conditional in

```
if (n % i == 0) printf("true\n");
```

tries to calculate

```
n % 0
```

in the first iteration, which results in a floating point exception. Start with `i = 1`.